# Is pixel_center_integer layout qualifier for gl_FragCoord supported in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to use the pixel_center_integer qualifier on gl_FragCoord, but saving out the returned coordinates makes it look like it's a no-op in Vulkan - coordinates are always offset by .5 for the fragment center.

My fragment shader code (simplified) looks like this:

```
layout(pixel_center_integer) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;
layout(location = 0) out vec2 outVal;

void main()
{
    outVal = gl_FragCoord.xy;
}
```

This is with the 1.0.37 Vulkan SDK, Windows 10, NVidia driver 376.53.

This of course is easy to work around but I couldn't find anything that suggested that it's not supported in Vulkan - glslangvalidator.exe happily compiles it to SPIR-V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [appendix A: validation rules for a module](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#spirvenv-module-validation):

> - The OriginLowerLeft execution mode **must** not be used; fragment entry points **must** declare OriginUpperLeft.
> - The PixelCenterInteger execution mode **must** not be used. Pixels are always centered at half-integer coordinates.